# Move Custom tab at top of left sidebar customer dashboard

Tags: magento2, custom, custom-block

I want to move my custom tab from bottom to top in customer dashboard left sidebar.

I tried below thing

```
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                    <block class="Training\Msg\Block\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-customlink">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Dashboard</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </referenceBlock>
<move element="customer-account-navigation-account-customlink" destination="customer_account_navigation" before="customer-account-navigation-orders-link"/>
```

[image]

What I actually need is I want to change **My Account** tab name according to the customer group, all set well but the tab is display at the bottom.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: please check answer i have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you doing well.

I'm also facing this issue but after some time have solved this.

Follow mentioned steps.

create file at **view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter" name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-4" template="Vendor_Module::account/navigation-delimiter.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1200</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-custom-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link Title</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">route/module/controller</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">180</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create Phtml file for **customer-account-navigation-delimiter-4** block.

**view/frontend/templates/account/navigation-delimiter.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Hope you have the result you want. :-)

Comment: Ok @Bhavin thank you for your answer :) let me try this one, will let you know what happened

Comment: Your answer is work for me after changes in block file like extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter and removed .phtml file as no need it in my case I already defined all the things into block file from Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current file +1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use block class `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface` and change sortOrder value.

Use this below code :

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Testing</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">500</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: But I need the label as per customer group condition that's why I used custom block where I set label into _tohtml method get the reference from Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current file

Comment: @Rohan Hapani thanks for your answer. it helps me a lot.

Comment: Thank you !! Keep sharing and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Training\Msg\Block\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-customlink" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Dashboard</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mukesh but it's not working I just tried, the tab position is as it is

Comment: @Hit's you should remove before"-" from  <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-"> in customer_account.xml

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: @Hit's is this done ?

Comment: No @Mukesh it's not working still position is as it is

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
```

to

```
<argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">500</argument>
```

Greater the number in `sortOrder` higher will be the link in the customer sidebar account navigation.

Comment: Ok @Anshu let me check this also

Comment: it's not working still position is as it is

Comment: @Hit's Have you cleaned cache?

Comment: @Hit's Implement class Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface to have sortOrder working correctly

Comment: Yes I did all the things but still it was not work for me

Comment: Yes I use which you mentioned class into @Bhavin's solution